# split string before next to last character

Tags: regex, r

I have a numeric variable, `DATE`, that represents dates where the last two characters are `MONTH` and the first one or two characters are `DAY`.  I would like to split the column into a separate column for `MONTH` and `DAY`.

I can do this with the following `R` code.  Although I was hoping for a simpler `regex` solution.

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
     ID     DATE     VARX
    A111     104        0
    A111     204        1
    A111    1004        4
    A111    2004        4
    B111    3004        2
    C111    3004        3
    C111     105        4
    C111    1005        4
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# remove the last two characters of a string
my.data$DAY   <- ifelse(nchar(my.data$DATE) == 3,
                        substr(my.data$DATE, nchar(my.data$DATE) - (nchar(my.data$DATE)-1), nchar(my.data$DATE) - (nchar(my.data$DATE)-1)),
                        substr(my.data$DATE, nchar(my.data$DATE) - (nchar(my.data$DATE)-1), nchar(my.data$DATE) - (nchar(my.data$DATE)-2)))

# keep the last two characters of a string

my.data$MONTH <- substr(my.data$DATE, (nchar(my.data$DATE)-1), nchar(my.data$DATE))

    ID DATE VARX DAY MONTH
1 A111  104    0   1    04
2 A111  204    1   2    04
3 A111 1004    4  10    04
4 A111 2004    4  20    04
5 B111 3004    2  30    04
6 C111 3004    3  30    04
7 C111  105    4   1    05
8 C111 1005    4  10    05
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: I think error was because when I updated the code, I left `%`.  Please try again

Comment: You don't need the `ifelse`: `my.data$DAY <- substr(my.data$DATE, 1, nchar(my.data$DATE) - 2)` But really, just use the `transform` solution given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use regular expressions, you can try:

```
dat <- c(104, 204, 1004, 2004, 3004, 3004, 105, 1005)


day <- gsub("(.*?)(..)", "\\1", dat)
day

[1] "1"  "2"  "10" "20" "30" "30" "1"  "10"

mth <- gsub("(.*?)(..)", "\\2", dat)
mth

[1] "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "05" "05"
```

---

You can also try a combination of `sprintf` and `substr`.

Here I wrap these into a function that gives your answer:

```
foo <- function(x){
  dat <- sprintf("%04d", x)
  cbind(day=substr(dat, 1, 2), month=substr(dat, 3, 4))
}

foo(dat)

foo(dat)
     day  month
[1,] "01" "04" 
[2,] "02" "04" 
[3,] "10" "04" 
[4,] "20" "04" 
[5,] "30" "04" 
[6,] "30" "04" 
[7,] "01" "05" 
[8,] "10" "05"
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few alternatives.  The first is the most concise.  The first two only use base R.

**1) numeric manipulation**

```
transform(my.data, MONTH = DATE %% 100, DAY = DATE %/% 100)
```

giving:

```
    ID DATE VARX MONTH DAY
1 A111  104    0     4   1
2 A111  204    1     4   2
3 A111 1004    4     4  10
4 A111 2004    4     4  20
5 B111 3004    2     4  30
6 C111 3004    3     4  30
7 C111  105    4     5   1
8 C111 1005    4     5  10
```

**2) sub**  This gives the same result as in (1).

```
spl <- function(x, replace) as.numeric(sub("(.*)(..)", replace, x))
transform(my.data, MONTH = spl(DATE, "\\2"), DAY = spl(DATE, "\\1"))
```

**3) strapply** applies `as.numeric` to the part of the match in parentheses and returns it.  This gives the same result as in (1).

```
library(gsubfn)

spl <- function(x, rx) strapply(x, rx, as.numeric, simplify = TRUE)
transform(my.data, MONTH = spl(DATE, ".*(..)"), DAY = spl(DATE, "(.*).."))
```

**Note**   They all return numeric columns which seems preferable but if you wanted to change that add  `as.character(...)` or an appropriate `sprintf` in (1), omit `as.numeric` in (2) or replace `as.numeric` in (3) with `c`.

**Update**  Added 2 and 3 and made some improvements.

Comment: This is a great answer and I used one of your suggestions.  However @Andrie's answer was closer to what I originally had in mind.  So, I gave him the check mark.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sprintf` and then use `substr`

```
my.data <- structure(list(ID = c("A111", "A111", "A111", "A111", "B111", 
"C111", "C111", "C111"), DATE = c(104L, 204L, 1004L, 2004L, 3004L, 
3004L, 105L, 1005L), VARX = c(0L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"DATE", "VARX"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))


val <- sprintf("%04d", my.data$DATE)
my.data$DAY <- as.numeric(substr(val,1,2))
my.data$MONTH <- substr(val,3,4)
my.data
#    ID DATE VARX DAY MONTH
#1 A111  104    0   1    04
#2 A111  204    1   2    04
#3 A111 1004    4  10    04
#4 A111 2004    4  20    04
#5 B111 3004    2  30    04
#6 C111 3004    3  30    04
#7 C111  105    4   1    05
#8 C111 1005    4  10    05
```

Or, you could try:

```
 library(stringr)
my.data1 <- cbind(my.data,  do.call(rbind,str_extract_all(my.data$DATE, perl('\\d+(?=[0-9]{2}$)|(?<=[0-9])\\d{2}'))))
colnames(my.data1)[4:5] <- c("DAY", "MONTH")

my.data1
#    ID DATE VARX DAY MONTH
#1 A111  104    0   1    04
#2 A111  204    1   2    04
#3 A111 1004    4  10    04
#4 A111 2004    4  20    04
#5 B111 3004    2  30    04
#6 C111 3004    3  30    04
#7 C111  105    4   1    05
#8 C111 1005    4  10    05
```

Comment: @Mark Miller. When I copy and paste the above code, I am getting the result as you showed.

Comment: Thank you.  I do too after changing `my.data$DAY <- as.numeric(val,1,2)` to `my.data$DAY <- as.numeric(substr(val,1,2))`

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see why complicate matters with using regular expressions since you already know that the last 2 digits correspond to the month and the remaining ones to the day. But if you really want to use a regular expression how about

```
my.data$DAY <- gsub("^([0-9])?([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])$", "\\1\\2", my.data$DATE)
my.data$MONTH <- gsub("^([0-9])?([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])$", "\\3\\4", my.data$DATE)
my.data
#    ID DATE VARX DAY MONTH
#  A111  104    0   1    04
#  A111  204    1   2    04
#  A111 1004    4  10    04
#  A111 2004    4  20    04
#  B111 3004    2  30    04
#  C111 3004    3  30    04
#  C111  105    4   1    05
#  C111 1005    4  10    05
```