# R - split string before two last digits in each column cell

Tags: regex, r, split

I have a csv with usernames in a column, followed by each user's feedback rating, out of 100.

E.g. `James89`

I hope to find a way to split the name and the rating, e.g. by inserting a comma before the two last digits using regex. Is this possible? And/or is there a better way to do this?

```
df1 = data.frame(Product = c(rep("ARCH78"), rep("AUSFUNGUY91"), rep("AddiesAndXans96"), rep("AfroBro79")))
```

The code above is a tiny excerpt of the data I'm dealing with. I hope to get this output:

```
ARCH    78
AUSFUNGUY    91
AddiesAndXans    96
AfroBro    79
```

I've tried this code (inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324471/split-string-before-next-to-last-character) answer:

```
df1$P2 <- gsub("(.*?)(..)", "\\1", df1$Product)
```

It seems to be working, but there's something wrong with the output:

```
ARCH78  AR
AUSFUNGUY91 AUUNY
AddiesAndXans96 AdesdXs
AfroBro79   AfBr9
```

Comment: Try `gsub("(\\d{2})$",",\\1",df1$Product)` if you want to insert  a comma before the last 2 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the following:

> I hope to find a way to split the name and the rating, e.g. by **inserting a comma before the two last digits using regex**.

You can achieve it with a mere

```
df1 = data.frame(Product = c(rep("ARCH78"), rep("AUSFUNGUY91"), rep("AddiesAndXans96"), rep("AfroBro79")))
gsub("(\\d{2})$",",\\1",df1$Product)
## => [1] "ARCH,78"          "AUSFUNGUY,91"     "AddiesAndXans,96" "AfroBro,79"
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/vRMk0m)

You can further adjust the replacement `",\\1"` that features a backreference `\1` to the last 2 digits.

Comment: Thank you for your time!